# Get all Objects stored in a given Subdirectory in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I have images being stored in Google Cloud Storage for an Android app, I decided to store everything in one bucket and use subdirectories to separate them into collections relevant to my application.

This means my object names look like: "ExampleImageCollection/ImageName". I'm using the Java API which lets me get a storage object with `storage.objects().get(bucketName, fileName)` or get multiple objects with `storage.objects.list(bucketName)`.

My question is can I get all objects which belong to ExampleImageCollection directory or in other words start with that in the filename in a way that isn't just listing every single object and then filtering it.

If not would it be better for me to just have different buckets instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [setPrefix](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Objects.List.html#setPrefix(java.lang.String)) method to restrict the listing results to, e.g., `ExampleImageCollection/`.